# fonts not being picked up in delphi 11

Tags: android, delphi

I made an application under Delphi 11 for Android 11. However, fonts don't work for all components like lables, ListView, etc.

I tried solutions on the Internet as follows:

I downloaded a `.ttf` file and added it to the deployment.

[image: deployment picture]

I changed the code of the `TAndroidFontGlyphManager.LoadResource()` procedure from the `FMX.FontGlyphs.Android` unit:

```
FontName := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, CurrentSettings.Family+'.ttf');// FontName : string 
if FileExists(FontName) then
  Typeface := TJTypeface.JavaClass.createFromFile(StringToJString(FontName))
else
  Typeface := TJTypeface.JavaClass.create(FamilyName, TypefaceFlag);
```

The font does not change, even for existing fonts like Aril.

Does anyone know why the fonts are not being picked up?

Comment: What is the value of CurrentSettings.Family? Note: It will be case sensitive

Comment: the value of CurrentSettings.Family is the the chosen font like Arial. i tried to replace CurrentSettings.Family with static string  `FontName:=TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'Fontfilenames.ttf');`

Comment: Why are you expecting it to find `'Fontfilenames.ttf'` when you are deploying `beIN Normal.ttf`?

Comment: `Fontfilenames.ttf` is just sample . i tried other files like Tahoma.

Comment: You need to provide *exactly* what you are doing for it to be a valid question. Giving a "sample" as an answer instead just confuses things